# How to open a fully functioning chrome browser using selenium WebDriver with python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I'm trying to open a web page, its opening in a new chrome window stripped of all the extensions and modules. I'm not able to emulate the certain behavior of the website using selenium chrome browser window but I'm able to do the same thing in a normal chrome window without any issues.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("remote_worksplace_link")

id_box = driver.find_element_by_id('Enter user name')
id_box.send_keys('123456')
pass_box = driver.find_element_by_id('passwd')
pass_box.send_keys('123abc')
login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('Log_On')
login_button.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(2)

launch_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('storeapp-icon ui-sortable-handle')
launch_button.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all extentions has its .crx file just you need to add those path

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('path_to_extension')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("url")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I'm trying to work with Citrix receiver extension, but there isn't any particular path for it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647363/unable-to-detect-citrix-receiver-using-selenium-webdriver-api

Comment: that is impossible. every extension has .crx file

Comment: [read this](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/receiver/chrome/current-release/deploy.html)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to locate the .crx file in _C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICA Client\Chrome_Extension_.